# Ruby: Array of Arrays to Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I have an Array of Arrays (imported from CSV file):

```
[[title1],[title2],[title3],[title4],[title5]],
[[song1],[author1],[bpm1],[key1],[energy1]],
...
[[song100],[author100],[bpm100],[key100],[energy100]].
```

and would like to convert it to an Array of Hashes like:

```
[{"title1"=>"song1","title2"=>"author1","title3"=>"bpm1","title4"=>"key1","title5"=>"energy1"}],
...
[{"title1"=>"song100","title2"=>"author100","title3"=>"bpm100","title4"=>"key100","title5"=>"energy100"}].
```

I used the code below but it doesn't work:

```
    require 'csv'
    csv=CSV.read('library.csv')

array_hash=[]
hash={}

for i in 1..(csv.size)

  hash1={}

    for n in 0..4

        a=csv[0][n]
        b=csv[i][n]
        hash1[a]=b
        hash.merge!(hash1)

    end

  array_hash.push(hash)

end
```

But I get:

```
> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass     from
> (irb):149:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'    from (irb):146:in
> `each'    from (irb):146:in `block in irb_binding'    from (irb):143:in
> `each'    from (irb):143  from
> /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong with this?
How to do the same using .each ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ruby `CSV` library has a [`to_hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-to_hash) function on `CSV::Row`, so you can do as below instead:

```
require 'csv'
rows = CSV.read('library.csv', headers: true).map(&:to_hash) #rows would return a list of hashes
```

Comment: Uh, yeah, I mean this works if you actually want to use what the standard library gives you.  :-)  Good answer... I didn't even realize that there was a `to_hash` function on `CSV::Row`.  I'm deleting my answer.